# How to convert Date Time to just Time?

Tags: excel

I have a column of date time. I have to remove the date part. I simple want to run a macro that will do that. WHen I record macro, do the delete and then stop, then run it on the next row, it gives the value below. How does one globalize so I can run on all rows this task?

```
 2017-06-26 14:41:00
```

the macro is this:

```
Sub Macro9()
'
' Macro9 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2:41:00 PM"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just format the cell to only show the time? Custom format `h:mm:ss AM/PM`

Comment: It was not working, when i brought in only the time ( the AMPM was not doing)

Comment: You can always just use the right function.  For example, =right(a1,8).  This assumes that there are no spaces after the time and the time always takes up 8 characters.  If those assumptions are not met you can still get what you want, it is just a little more invloved.  Do you want to convert it from military time to AM/PM.  If so you'll have to take another approach.

Comment: Yes we want to change from military to AM PM.I am surprised that the format does not work on the date time.

Comment: Is your "date time" an actual date/time value, or is it text?  E.g. if you wrote a formula in Excel that was `=LEN(A1)` (assuming your date/time is in cell A1) does it return a value of 19 (the number of characters in `2017-06-26 14:41:00`) or does it return 16 (the number of characters in `42912.6118055556`, which is the date/time value)?

Comment: FYI I changed the title of your question, please try and keep them meaningful so when people search later they may find an answer and not have to ask the same question, your previous title of "A simple excel macro" doesn't explain what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple macro to accomplish what you are looking to do.  I assumed that you wanted to convert from military time to AM/PM.  You will have to adjust the locations of cells to fit your spreadsheet.  This is just going through all of the values in column A and turning them into just AM/PM time and spitting them out in coulmn B.  Instead of looping through all of the rows you could also define your own single input function with the same logic.

```
Sub test()

Dim dt As String
Dim tm As String
Dim hr As String
Dim row_ct As Integer

row_ct = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row


For i = 1 To row_ct
    dt = Cells(i, 1)
    tm = Right(Cells(i, 1), 8)
    hr = Left(tm, 2)

    If hr < 12 Then
        tm = tm & " AM"
    ElseIf hr = 12 Then tm = tm & " PM"
    ElseIf hr > 12 and hr - 12 < 10 then tm = 0 & (Left(tm, 2) - 12) & Right(tm, 6) & " PM"
    Else: tm = left(tm, 2) - 12 & right(tm, 6) & " PM"
    End If

    Cells(i, 2) = tm
Next i


End Sub
```

Here is how you can make a custom function that handles this:

```
Function tm(date_time)

If Left(Right(date_time, 8), 2) < 12 Then
    tm = Right(date_time, 8) & " AM"
ElseIf Left(Right(date_time, 8), 2) = 12 Then tm = Right(date_time, 8) & " PM"
ElseIf Left(Right(date_time, 8), 2) > 12 Then tm = Left(Right(date_time, 8), 2)- 12 & Right(date_time, 6) & " PM"`
End If

End Function
```

Depending on the application, one will probably work better than the other.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the hr<12 fails on type mismatch

Comment: I found an error in the code and edited it try it again now.